# Cuál es la mejor manera de filtrar un array, comparando propiedades con otro array?

Tags: javascript, filtro

Tengo dos arrays, uno de usuariosViejos y otro de usuariosUpdated, y lo que yo quiero es conseguir un array que me diga cuales fueron los usuarios agregados (los que están en usuarios updated y no están en usuariosViejos).

```
const usuariosViejos = [
   { name: 'Fede', id: 1 },
   { name: 'Marce', id: 2 },
];

const usuariosUpdated = [
   { name: 'Fede', id: 1 },
   { name: 'Marce', id: 2 },
   { name: 'Ale', id: 3 },
   { name: 'Julian', id: 4 },
];
```

Cual sería la manera mas efectiva (o alguna que funcione al menos), para comparar los ids entre ambos y dejar un nuevo array usuariosAgregados, con aquellos usuarios que están en usuariosUpdated y no están en usuariosViejos?

En este caso el array usuarios agregados quedaria así:

```
const usuariosAgregados = [
  { name: 'Ale', id: 3 },
  { name: 'Julian', id: 4 }
```

Comment: Hola, recuerda que si eres nuevo puedes darle un vistazo a [ask], ¿qué has intentado hasta el momento para obtener lo que buscas?

Answer (score 0):

```
let usuariosViejosAux = usuariosViejos;
let usuariosAgregados = [];
for(let i=0; i<usuariosUpdated.length; i++){
    for(let j=0; j<usuariosViejosAux.length; j++){
        if(usuariosUpdated[i].id === usuariosViejosAux[j].id){
            usuariosViejosAux.splice(j, 1);// elimino elemento para no comparar de nuevo y así reducir iteraciones
            break;
        }  
        usuariosAgregados.push(usuariosUpdated[i])
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Jair, recuerda que si eres nuevo puedes darle un vistado a [ask]